# Removing each element at the value in each key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
sample_dict = {'i.year': ['1997', '1997'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}
```

How do we compare each element in i.year and j.year, and if the elements are equal to each other, than delete the element at that index in the value
at each key and than move on to the next element and continue the process. The length of each value will always be the same. *With no use of imports*

So basically what I'm trying to say is this:

For the sake of this question compare just the elements in i.year and j.year:

```
-> {'i.year': ['1997', '1997'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}
-> The first element in i.year is equal to the first element in j.year, so delete the first element in each value in every key.
```

We get:

```
-> {'i.year': ['1997'], 'i.month': ['April'], 'j.month': ['April'], 'j.year': ['2003']}
-> The element now in i.year and j.year is the same so we're done. Return that dictionary
```

Another example:

```
-> {'i.year': ['1997', '1997', '2009'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003', '2010']}
-> The first element in i.year is equal to the first element in j.year, so delete the first element in each value in every key.
```

We get:

```
-> {'i.year': ['1997', '2009'], 'i.month': ['April', 'June'], 'j.month': ['April', 'June'], 'j.year': ['2003', '2010']}
-> Now the first element in i.year and j.year are different so we move to the next element which is '2009' and '2010'
-> '2009' and '2010' are different so we move to the next element, since there's none we are done. Return that dictionary.
```

Last example:

```
-> {'i.year': ['1996', '1997', '2010'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003', '2010']}
-> The first element in i.year is not equal to the first element in j.year, so we move on to the next element.
-> '1997' does not equal to '2003' so we move on to the next element
-> '2010' is equal to '2010' so we delete each element in every key at the index
```

We get:

```
-> {'i.year': ['1996', '1997'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}
-> There are no more elements to move on to, so we are done, we return this dictionary.
```

I have this idea but cant turn it into python code:

For every element in i.month loop through every element in j.year, and if the elements are not equal loop through the entire dictionary and remove the element
at that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first find the indexes where the elements in `i.year` and `j.year` are different, and then iterate over dict and filter out items that are not at those indexes:

```
def solve(d, *keys):
    indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(zip(*(d[k] for k in keys)))
                                                                if len(set(x)) != 1]
    return {k:[v[x] for x in indexes] for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> d = {'i.year': ['1997', '1997'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}
>>> solve(d, 'i.year', 'j.year')
{'i.year': ['1997'], 'j.month': ['April'], 'i.month': ['April'], 'j.year': ['2003']}

>>> d = {'i.year': ['1997', '1997', '2009'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003', '2010']}
>>> solve(d, 'i.year', 'j.year')
{'i.year': ['1997', '2009'], 'j.month': ['April', 'June'], 'i.month': ['April', 'June'], 'j.year': ['2003', '2010']}

>>> d = {'i.year': ['1996', '1997', '2010'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April', 'June'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003', '2010']}
>>> solve(d, 'i.year', 'j.year')
{'i.year': ['1996', '1997'], 'j.month': ['March', 'April'], 'i.month': ['March', 'April'], 'j.year': ['1997', '2003']}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ashwini, however is there a way to do this without using zip?

Comment: @Sc4r Yes you can, then you'll have to write your [version of zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), which is unnecessary here.

Comment: Oh, thanks, and what line do I modify in your code so instead of is equal we have is greater.